# How to construct mongoose Find from url query string?

Tags: express, mongoose, find, query-string

I have an object schema as

```
var book = new Schema ({
 name: {type: String},
 code: {type: String}
});

Sample content is 
{
  name: "Jungle Book",
  code: "Jungle"
}
{
  name: "Java Book",
  code: "Java"
}
```

I have a http GET request to my Express server as

```
http://localhost:port/api/book?name=Jung
```

This API invocation is expected to return all books that have the name starting with "Jung"

In my experess implementation, I have

```
exports.getBooks = function(req, res, next) {
  var query = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query;

  Book.find({"name": /^query.name/}).exec(function(err, books){
    if(err){ res.status(400).json(
           { success: false, 
             message: 'Error processing request '+ err
           }); 
         }
    res.status(201).send(books);
  });
};
```

I receive an empty array, the search is not successful. However when I do an exact match like below its successful.

```
Book.find({"name": query.name})....
```

Pleases suggest how to perform a 'find' with 'starts with' operation from a query parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose supports regexp, so an other option is:

```
let regexp = new RegExp("^" + query.name);
Book.find({ name: regexp });
```

Or try:

```
let data = {"name": /^query.name/};

Book.find(data, function(err, books) {
    if(err) {
        res.status(400).json({
            success: false, 
            message: 'Error processing request ' + err
        }); 
    };
    res.status(201).send(books);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both the options. I was successful with option 1 with RegExp. Not sure why I was not successful with option 2.